# How to find a root element that contains specific text using nested id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to select a root element that contains a specific text using nested div id in Query. For example:

```
<div>...
   <div id="parentDiv1">
    <span>
      ....
      <span>
       .....
         <div>..</div>
         <div id="myId1">...</div>
      </span>
    ....
  </span>
</div>
</div>

<div id="parentDiv2">
<span>
 ....
   <h2>..</h2>
  <span>
     .....
       <div>..</div>
       <div id="myId2">...</div>
  </span>
  ....
</span>
</div>
```

Now, I need to select a div which has the id `parentDiv` with a nested div having id `#myId1`.

I find more difficult in this case. I know this is a complex case. Can anybody help me please.

Comment: Specific text or id?

Comment: Think it through. You know exactly what you want to select, so go to the jquery api docs and find the methods you need to do it.

Comment: I need to select a div id which contains text parentDiv with the nested id #myId1. I searched in many forums. But i could not find a answer

Comment: @GreenComputers Ihave edited my answer. SEe now if it helps

Comment: What do you mean by "select a div id"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding the question correctly, this should work:

```
$("div:contains('parentDiv')").has("#myId1");
```

or if you need just the id of the div with those attributes:

```
$("div:contains('parentDiv')").has("#myId1").attr('id');
```

For more info check out:

[Jquery :contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)